# Filtering SQL using a oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know if the following is possible

For example I have a shoe factory. In this factory I have a production line,  Every step in this production line is recorded into the oracle database.

if the shoe has completed a production step the result is = 1

example table

```
Shoe_nr    production step      result
1              1                 1 
1              2                 1
1              3
2              1                 1
2              2                 1 
2              3               
3              1 
3              2 
3              3
```

Now the question, is it possible to filter out production step 3 where only the shoes have passed production step 2 which is equal to 1 in result.

I know if it can be done it's probably very easy but if you dont know i found out it's a little bit tricky.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: And what results would you want?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with IN and a Subselect

```
select * 
from shoes
where shoe.id in (
    select shoe.id
    from shoes
    where production_step = 2
    and result = 1
)
and production_step = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be one option; see comments within code (lines #1 - 12 represent sample data; you already have that and don't type it. Query you might be interested in begins at line #13).

```
SQL> with shoes (shoe_nr, production_step, result) as
  2  -- sample data
  3    (select 1, 1, 1    from dual union all
  4     select 1, 2, 1    from dual union all
  5     select 1, 3, null from dual union all
  6     select 2, 1, 1    from dual union all
  7     select 2, 2, 1    from dual union all
  8     select 2, 3, null from dual union all
  9     select 3, 1, null from dual union all
 10     select 3, 2, null from dual union all
 11     select 3, 3, null from dual
 12    ),
 13  -- which shoes' production step #3 should be skipped?
 14  skip as
 15    (select shoe_nr
 16     from shoes
 17     where production_step = 2
 18       and result = 1
 19    )
 20  -- finally:
 21  select a.shoe_nr, a.production_step, a.result
 22  from shoes a
 23  where (a.shoe_nr, a.production_step) not in (select b.shoe_nr, 3
 24                                               from skip b
 25                                              )
 26  order by a.shoe_nr, a.production_step;

   SHOE_NR PRODUCTION_STEP     RESULT
---------- --------------- ----------
         1               1          1
         1               2          1
         2               1          1
         2               2          1
         3               1
         3               2
         3               3

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the `shoe_nr` that satisfy the condition, you can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select shoe_nr
from mytable
group by shoe_nr
having 
    max(case when production_step = 2 then result end) = 0
    and max(case when production_step = 3 then 1 end) = 1
```

If you want the entire row corresponding to this `shoe_nr` at step 3, use window functions instead:

```
select 1
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        max(case when production_step = 2 then result end) 
            over(partition by shoe_nr) as has_completed_step_2
    from mytable t
) t
where production_step = 3 and has_completed_step_2 = 0
```